# How should I lay my model in ember in case of this hasMany relations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, ember.js

The JSON i send from the server looks like this,

```
{"selectFill":{"user":[{"userId":"Gru","department":"Villain"},{"userId":"Sulley","department":"Scare"},{"userId":"Popeye","department":"Sailer"}]}}
```

and my model looks like this,

```
    App.SelectFill = DS.Model.extend({
    users: DS.hasMany('user',{
        embedded: true
    })
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    userId: DS.attr('string'),
    department: DS.attr('department')
});

App.SelectFillSerializer = DS.WebAPISerializer.extend({
    extractArray: function (store, type, payload, id, requestType) {

        var primaryTypeName = type.typeKey;

        var typeName = primaryTypeName,
            type = store.modelFor(typeName);

        var selectFill = [];
        selectFill.push(payload.selectFill);
        var newi = {};
        newi[typeName] = selectFill;

        return this._super(store, type, newi, id, requestType);
    }
});
```

I inspected the code with the ember inspector in Chrome debugger, i can see 1 record in SelectFill, but its empty. The User record is also empty.
Could you please tell me, what i'm doing wrong here?I'm new to Ember, i tried to step into the Ember source code and my head, and my head start spinning. Does everyone also debug their code by going deep down into Ember source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert the data into this format, and you need ids on all of you record (if you want userId to be the id of user, remove it from the model definition and add it to the adapter)

```
{
  "selectFill":
    {
      id:'something',
      "users":['Gru', 'Sulley','Popeye']
    },
  "users":[
    {"userId":"Gru","department":"Villain"},
    {"userId":"Sulley","department":"Scare"},
    {"userId":"Popeye","department":"Sailer"}]
  }

App.UserAdapter = DS....extend({

   primaryKey: 'userId'
});
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: thank you @kingpin2k, that did work!!! i just modify my extractarray to   
meet the requirement...